# Confusion about _Lock_policy in libstdc++

Tags: c++, multithreading, std, libstdc++, memory-barriers

I'm reading the implements of std::shared_ptr of libstdc++, and I noticed that libstdc++ has three locking policies: _S_single, _S_mutex, and _S_atomic (see [here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/ext/concurrence.h#L49)), and the lock policy would affect the specialization of class _Sp_counted_base ([_M_add_ref](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/shared_ptr_base.h#L251) and [_M_release](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/shared_ptr_base.h#L169))

Below is the code snippet：

```
_M_release_last_use() noexcept
{
    _GLIBCXX_SYNCHRONIZATION_HAPPENS_AFTER(&_M_use_count);
    _M_dispose();
    // There must be a memory barrier between dispose() and destroy()
    // to ensure that the effects of dispose() are observed in the
    // thread that runs destroy().
    // See http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2005-11/msg00136.html
    if (_Mutex_base<_Lp>::_S_need_barriers)
    {
        __atomic_thread_fence (__ATOMIC_ACQ_REL);
    }

    // Be race-detector-friendly.  For more info see bits/c++config.
    _GLIBCXX_SYNCHRONIZATION_HAPPENS_BEFORE(&_M_weak_count);
    if (__gnu_cxx::__exchange_and_add_dispatch(&_M_weak_count,
                                               -1) == 1)
    {
        _GLIBCXX_SYNCHRONIZATION_HAPPENS_AFTER(&_M_weak_count);
        _M_destroy();
    }
  }
 
  template<>
  inline bool
  _Sp_counted_base<_S_mutex>::
  _M_add_ref_lock_nothrow() noexcept
  {
     __gnu_cxx::__scoped_lock sentry(*this);
    if (__gnu_cxx::__exchange_and_add_dispatch(&_M_use_count, 1) == 0)
    {
         _M_use_count = 0;
         return false;
     }
     return true;
   }
```

my questions are:

1. When using the _S_mutex locking policy, the __exchange_and_add_dispatch function may only guarantee atomicity, but may not guarantee that it is fully fenced, am I right?
2. and because of 1, is the purpose of '__atomic_thread_fence (__ATOMIC_ACQ_REL)' to ensure that when thread A invoking _M_dispose, no thread will invoke _M_destory (so that thread A could never access a destroyed member(eg: _M_ptr) inside the function '_M_dispose'?
3. What puzzles me most is that if 1 and 2 are both correct, then why there is no need to add a thread fence before invoking the '_M_dispose'? (because the objects managed by _Sp_counted_base and _Sp_counted_base itself have the same problem when the reference count is dropped to zero)

Comment: There is no such thing as glibc++

Comment: @Jonathan Wakely sry, it should be libstdc++, I corrected it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of this is answered in the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/memory.html#shared_ptr.thread) and at the URL shown in the code you quoted.

> 1. When using the _S_mutex locking policy, the __exchange_and_add_dispatch function may only guarantee atomicity, but may not guarantee that it is fully fenced, am I right?

Yes.

> 2. and because of 1, is the purpose of '__atomic_thread_fence (__ATOMIC_ACQ_REL)' to ensure that when thread A invoking _M_dispose, no thread will invoke _M_destory (so that thread A could never access a destroyed member(eg: _M_ptr) inside the function '_M_dispose'?

No, that can't happen. When `_M_release_last_use()` starts executing `_M_weak_count >= 1`, and `_M_destroy()` function won't be called until after `_M_weak_count` is decremented, and so `_M_ptr` remains valid during the `_M_dispose()` call. If `_M_weak_count==2` and another thread is decrementing it at the same time as `_M_release_last_use()` runs, then there is a race to see which thread decrements first, and so you don't know which thread will run `_M_destroy()`. But whichever thread it is, `_M_dispose()` already finished before `_M_release_last_use()` does its decrement.

The reason for the memory barrier is that `_M_dispose()` invokes the deleter, which runs user-defined code. That code could have arbitrary side effects, touching other objects in the program. The `_M_destroy()` function uses `operator delete` or an allocator to release the memory, which could also have arbitrary side effects (if the program has replaced `operator delete`, or the `shared_ptr` was constructed with a custom allocator). The memory barrier ensures that the effects of the deleter are synchronized with the effects of the deallocation. The library doesn't know what those effects are, but it doesn't matter, the code still ensures they synchronize.

> 3. What puzzles me most is that if 1 and 2 are both correct,

They are not.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot. So there is no need to add `thread_fence` under _S_atomic because `__exchange_and_add_dispatch(&_M_weak_count)` already guaranteed the visiablity of `_M_dispose`?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: another question, how does '_Sp_counted_base' guarantee the  'SYNC_HAPPENS_BEFORE' relationships around 'exchange_and_add' under _S_mutex policy? AFK, atomic ref counters should add ACQ/REL memory fences when decreasing the ref counter.

Comment: Isn't that what the`__atomic_thread_fence` is for? I don't really care, I don't think any target still uses the `_S_mutex` policy. All targets support atomic built-ins on `_Atomic_word` now.

Comment: OK, there is still one thing I don't understand, why `_M_add_ref_lock` specified __ATOMIC_ACQ_REL when compare_exchange_n return true? [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70331658/how-to-implement-stdweak-ptrlock-with-atomic-operations)